# Anführungszeichen und ™

Tags: quotes, neologism, gestures

Man sieht des Öfteren (und seltener hört man es auch ausbuchstabiert) das Zeichen für *Unregistered Trade Mark* (ein hochgestelltes TM: ™), zum Beispiel in [diesem Beitrag](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/wie-k%C3%B6nnen-wir-den-themenbereich-um-geschlechtergerechte-sprache-objektiv-halten):

> Fragen zum Thema geschlechtergerechte Sprache, generisches Maskulinum, u. Ä. ziehen unweigerlich Diskussionen und Kommentare dazu an, was denn nun richtig™ ist.

Es scheint verdeutlichen zu sollen, dass es sich um eine fremde Meinung handelt oder dass der Schreiber (Sprecher) der angeführten Aussage nicht zustimmt oder dass die angeführte Aussage einen Anspruch auf Richtigkeit erhebt, den der Sprecher nicht anerkennt.

Inwiefern unterscheidet sich der Gebrauch vom Gebrauch der Anführungszeichen (wenn diese etwa um einzelne Wörter oder ironisch gesetzt oder mit den Händen als Gänsefüßchen angedeutet werden)?
Was bietet das TM (außerhalb wirtschaftlicher Kontexte), was sich nicht mit Anführungszeichen ausdrücken lässt?

Das ist zwar nicht ausschließlich, aber auch ein Phänomen der geschriebenen und gesprochenen deutschen Sprache, und insofern hier relevant.

Comment: Just to chime in.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. Was hat ein Symbol aus dem amerikanischen Wirtschaftsrecht mit Zitaten zu tun?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ja, vielleicht sollte ich diese Frage von dir genau so in meiner Frage ergänzen. Aber das Symbol wird ja in der deutschen Sprache außerhalb seiner ursprünglich wirtschaftlichen Bedeutung verwandt.

Comment: Ich habe dieses Symbol noch nie in einer anderen Bedeutung als der ursprünglich wirtschaftlichen gesehen. In welchem Kontext (außer in dem in Frage verlinkten Beispiel) ist die alternative Verwendung üblich?

Comment: Ich kenne die Verwendung vom ™-Zeichen als ironisches Stilmittel auch nur in der englischen Sprache und habe das glaube ich bisher noch nie in Deutsch gesehen. Die Verwendung des Zeichens ™ hat in Deutschland auch nicht die rechtliche Bedeutung wie in England oder USA („ich erhebe Anspruch auf ...“), die sich in der ironischen Verwendung wiederspiegelt. Markenschutz besteht in Deutschland so bald gewisse rechtliche Bedinungen erfüllt sind. Der Inhaber der Marke muss dafür nicht aktiv den Markenschutz beanspruchen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich kenne einige jüngere Leute, die *TM* gelegentlich ironisch verwenden, mündlich. Schriftlich ist es mir bisher nur einige Male im Internet aufgefallen. Es ist etwas schwierig, nach dem Zeichen zu suchen, ohne seine eigentliche Bedeutung zu finden, aber hier wird es einige Male verwendet: http://playtogether-podcast.de/28-kettenbriefvz/

Comment: @jarnbjo: Ich glaube du verwechselt Urheberrecht mit Markenschutz. Eine Marke muss man sehr wohl anmelden (nämlich am Patentamt) und das kostet auch eine Menge Geld. Aber wer ein Werks erschaffen hat, muss gar nichts extra machen, um den vollen Schutz des Urheberrechts zu genießen. Man muss lediglich sein Recht einklagen wenn es verletzt wurde, aber vorher ist nichts weiter zu tun als ein Werk zu erschaffen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Nein, ich verwechsle nichts. Eine Marke muss in Deutschland nicht eingetragen sein, um Schutz zu genießen. Eine Eintragung erleichtert aber die Beweislage im Streitfall. Siehe MarkenG § 4(2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ein Warenzeichen unterscheidet sich von einem generischen Begriff
dadurch, daß es nicht jeder nach Belieben benutzen darf.
Papiertaschentücher darf jeder auf den Markt bringen, aber welche
Tücher als Tempo™-Taschentücher verkauft werden, bestimmt allein
der Inhaber das Warenzeichens "Tempo".

Das TM als Stilmittel spielt auf diesen Alleinvertretungsanspruch an.
Wer also sagt, "Benutz ein richtiges™ Betriebssystem", der
nimmt sich damit schon heraus, selbst zu definieren, welche
Betriebssysteme in diesem Kontext richtig oder nicht richtig sind,
und wer von "richtiger™ geschlechtergerechter Sprache" spricht,
der legt den Freunden geschlechtergerechter Sprache damit in den
Mund, daß sie typischerweise genau eine Form des
Genderns für richtig und jede andere für indiskutabel halten.

Anführungszeichen sind demgegenüber weniger spezifisch.
Im Alltag werden sie zur Markierung ironischer Aussagen verwendet,
zur Markierung von Zitaten,
aber auch um zu zeigen, daß ein Wort im übertragenen Sinn gebraucht
wird, oder daß man sich von einer Formulierung distanziert.

Comment: Anführungsstriche werden in erster Linie für die Darstellung direkter Rede benutzt. Die Nutzung für Ironie und Distanzierung ist zwar verbreitet, aber eine Unsitte. Völliger Humbug ist die Markierung von Metaphern. Es kann sinnvoll sein einen Sprung in die Metasprache so zu kennzeichnen, wenn ansonsten Verwechslungsgefahr besteht, also nicht wenn man sagt, das Wort kurz sei kurz, weil aus dem Satzgefüge da jeder ein Wort als Wort erwartet, aber wenn ich sage "kurz" sei ein kurzes Wort ergibt sich, dass ich das Wort "kurz" meine erst im Nachhinein, so dass Anführungsstriche Sinn haben.

Comment: Eine Nutzung von Anführungsstrichen zu vielen unterschiedlichen Zwecken widerspricht dem Zweck, durch Ausdrucksmittel eine Bedeutung klar zu machen. Es verwirrt nur.

Comment: @userunknown Meine Aussage war deskriptiv, nicht práskriptiv. Abgesehen davon ist die Verwendung eines einzigen sprachlichen oder typographischen Ausdrucksmittels zu unterschiedlichen Zwecken die Regel, nicht die Ausnahme.

Comment: Wer Metaphern in Anführungsstriche setzt, macht es schlicht falsch. Ironie ist versteckte Spott, Anführungsstriche stellen ihn aber aus. Das wäre also, wenn, dann Häme, die man ausdrückt.

Comment: Die Antwort scheint nur einen speziellen Fall zu beschreiben. Wo ist beispielsweise der vom Sprecher geforderte Alleinvertretungsanspruch im treffenden Beispiel aus [tofros Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/48189/5999), "Früher(TM) war alles besser."?

Answer (score 6):

Mit diesem Stilmittel möchte der Schreiber durch Anfügen eines Trademark-Zeichens "(TM)" darauf hinweisen, daß er bewußt ein Klischee im Sinne von Selbstironie  bemüht.

Das Klischee wird bei dem Trademark-Gag dann als ein gedachter Rechteinhaber 
personifiziert und somit durch das "(TM)" auf eben jenes Klischee verwiesen.

> Früher(TM) war alles besser.

Comment: Das trifft es meinem Eindruck nach sehr gut. Nun bin ich nur am Überlegen, ob [Uwes Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/48190/5999) an sich gleichbedeutend ist, oder ob sie einen Spezialfall von deiner Antwort beschreibt ... oder ob sie letztendlich etwas anderes aussagt.

Comment: Entschuldige, aber Du redest wirr. "Ein Klischee im Sinne von Selbstironie", was soll das sein? Was soll das Klischee von "Früher" sein? Inwiefern kann "Früher" selbstironisch sein? "Das Klischee wird ... als ein gedachter Rechteinhaber personifiziert" - was? Auf welchen gedachten Rechteinhaber wird durch TM bei "früher" verwiesen? Der ganze Satz "Früher war alles besser" kann ein Klischee sein. Inwiefern soll die Handelsmarke das verdeutlichen?

Comment: @userunknown Ich verstehe sowohl tofros Antwort als auch deine Kritik an ihr. (Er hätte seine Beobachtung etwas genauer ausführen können.) Allerdings redest auch du wirr: "TM" ist keine Handelsmarke (wie du im letzten Satz sagst) sondern vielmehr ein Hinweis darauf, dass es sich beim damit geschmückten Wort um den Namen einer solchen handelt. Man könnte "TM" also allenfalls als Handelsmarkenmarkierung bezeichnen. Etwas Präzision brauchen wir bei diesem Thema schon...

Answer (score 1):

™ und (TM) sind der *Amerikalativ*.

Ein Superlativ, der nicht mehr gesteigert werden kann. Wahlloses Einstreuen erwünscht, um die Absurdität zu verdeutlichen, alles, was aus Amerika kommt, unreflektiert hochzujubeln.

> Der beste™ Galax-3000-Eimer™, den die Welt je™ gesehen hat.

Ich denke da immer an dieses schlecht synchronisierte amerikanische Werbefernsehen, mit dem uns die Impulskaufsender™ in den 1990ern belustigt haben. Von da aus geht's direkt zum Tarotkartenlegen bei 9Live.

Comment: Nicht zu vernachlässigen ist auch die Rolle des magischen Denkens: Der Amerikaner glaubt, wenn er hinter seinem Firmennamen eine Beschwörungsformel wie "TM" aufsagt, besonderen Schutz seiner Geister oder Götter für diese Firma zu erwirken. In Europa haben wir dieses Denken mit der Renaissance überwunden. Leider ist magisches Denken aber ansteckend, und so verbreitet es sich nun auch in der ersten Welt wieder.